# doing post call to controller from other php file

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a file that i added to my autoload file and i am trying to do a call to a controller function.

The problem is that this function is also called from my .js files and the method i want to call is accepting `Input` variables which i passed on with tha ajax call. Now my question is how i can call the controller from another php file and pass in post variables.

I can use the `Route::post` method but how can i pass post variables?

I was told that i can do it through the ioc but i have no idea how this would work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route::post()` is used for registering routes in your app.
Laravel comes with a Client class (from Symfony) that you can use for requests to an url.

But if you want to call a method from another controller, just do `$res = FooController::method();`